# what should i index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

i'm a complete index dummie, but I've read and watched quite a bit of vids on indexing but i just can't seem to figure it out.

the table looks like the following:

```
ID          int
ComponentId int
Value       float
TimeStamp   datetime
```

imagine this database having about 2 million records and i would like to do something like the following:

```
SELECT Value
FROM Log 
WHERE ComponentId = X 
AND TimeStamp >= SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()),112)
```

That should get me all the values for a selected component within the last 24 hours

And im really wondering if i should index this on ComponentId, Timestamp or both

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create `covering index` on the table like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_IndexName ON dbo.TableName(ComponentId, TimeStamp) 
INCLUDE(Value)
```

This should improve the performance of your query with index seek. Also `Value` will be stored in the leafs of the index so you get rid of `lookups` as data that you are selecting is already in your index.

Comment: wil this hurt my inserting badly? because there are devices in our factory that generate quite a bit of data

Comment: I can't say how much it will hurt, but definitely it will hurt. Your question is always urgent when you choose between insertion/deletion/update and select performance. You should check.

Comment: Ill test it like this for a while, after some testing i'll know for sure,

Comment: Before qand after every change take metrics: 1. Whatever performance metrics you can get. 2. Query plans.

Answer (score 2):

you should add composite along with covering index using with `ComponentId, Timestamp`.

```
create index ix_Log_ComponentId_Timestamp on log(ComponentId, Timestamp) include (value)
```

Also, no need to add select before `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()),112)`

Comment: The extra select was an error, while creating the post i accidentally copied to much from an example. when i tried running the query i didn't work so i deleted it but forgot too delete it from the form

Comment: I'd argue no need for the convert entirely, just keep the dateadd.